# Automatically creating a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to automatically create the following list:

```
[Slot('1A', '0', 0), Slot('2A', '0', 0),
 Slot('1B', '0', 0], Slot ('2B,'0', 0), ....]
```

By defining slot as:

```
class Slot:
    def __init__(self, address , card, stat):
        self.address = address
        self.card = card
        self.stat = stat


board = []
for i in range(1, 13):
    for j in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']:
        board.append(Slot ((str(i)+j,'0', 0)))
print(board)
```

Using Python 3.5 in Windows. What is wrong? How I can do that? Thanks.

Comment: So what's  wrong :-)? What's the output and what's wrong with it?

Comment: I'm quite inclined to edit the `TypeError` in there but not entirely sure it's a proper action to take.

Comment: Jim answer was very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have enclosed all arguments to `Slot` in a single parenthesis thereby passing a single argument to an `__init__` that expects three (and the `TypeError` raised hints to that). Remove the unnecessary set of parenthesis:

```
board.append(Slot(str(i)+j,'0', 0))
```

and it works fine.

As an addendum, `print(board)` will return a quite unpleasant view of the objects, I'd suggest overloading `__str__` and `__repr__` to get a better view of the created objects:

```
class Slot:
    def __init__(self, address , card, stat):
        self.address = address
        self.card = card
        self.stat = stat

    def __str__(self):
        return "Slot: ({0}, {1}, {2})".format(self.address, self.card, self.stat)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
```

Now `print(board)` prints:

```
print(board)
[Slot: (1A, 0, 0), Slot: (1B, 0, 0),..., Slot: (12H, 0, 0), Slot: (12I, 0, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a single tuple to the constructor. If you remove the parentheses, your code is golden.

```
From:
board.append(Slot ((str(i)+j,'0', 0)))
To:
board.append(Slot(str(i)+j,'0', 0))
```